# For-loop with two variables at once

Tags: variables, object, if-statement, for-loop, python-3.x

**Background:**
I have this program where the user writes two teams that faced each other and their score and I'm supposed to update a table accordingly. I have all the teams stored as objects with parameters such as name,games,win,goals etc.

**My problem:**
Is there any way for me to handle both team-inputs and update their respective stats all at once? Right now I'm using 2 different for-loops that basically do the same thing with some minor adjustments.

**My program now (parts of it):**
I use this for loop for the homeTeam and a very similar one for the other team.

```
for i in self.teams:

        if homeTeam.lower() == i.name.lower():
            i.games += 1

            goal_dif_Split = i.goal_dif.split("-")
            goal_dif_Split[0] = int(goal_dif_Split[0])+ scoreH
            goal_dif_Split[1] = int(goal_dif_Split[1])+ scoreA

            i.goal_dif = str(goal_dif_Split[0])+"-"+str(goal_dif_Split[1])

            if scoreH > scoreA:
                i.win += 1
                i.points += 3
            elif scoreH < scoreA:
                i.loss += 1
            else:
                i.tie += 1
                i.points += 1
```

*As requested from the comments:*

**1. This is how the team-inputs look like**:

```
        homeTeam = input ("Hometeam: ")
        awayTeam = input ("Awayteam: ")
        score = input ("Score: ")
```

**2. This is the second for-loop:**

```
     for j in self.teams:

        if awayTeam.lower() == j.name.lower():
            j.games += 1

            goal_dif_Split = j.goal_dif.split("-")
            goal_dif_Split[0] = int(goal_dif_Split[0])+ scoreA
            goal_dif_Split[1] = int(goal_dif_Split[1])+ scoreH

            j.goal_dif = str(goal_dif_Split[0])+"-"+str(goal_dif_Split[1])

            if scoreA > scoreH:
                j.win += 1
                j.points += 3
            elif scoreA < scoreH:
                j.loss += 1
            else:
                j.tie += 1
                j.points += 1
```

Comment: Could you also post the second loop to clarify?

Comment: 1. what does a team-input look like? 2. can you remove all but 1 attribute that is updated? for more clarity. thanks!

Comment: Second loop and team-inputs added as requested!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution - 
why not create a function that **execute exactly that for loop**?

Then - just duplicate the function call for the other team.

Answer (score 0):

Simulate the reality. Initially, the table of statistics is empty. Let it be a dictionary where the name is a key, and the stats object is the value.

When you get `name1 - name2 ... 3:2`, you have to update exactly the two records. You should not loop through all of the teams. The dictionary is designed for searching the value (record) by name. Something like:

```
table = {} # initially empty
...

# parse the result to get...
homeTeam = 'red onions'
homeResult = 3

guestTeam = 'blue shits'
guestResult = 2

# Get the stats objects for the teams.
# The Stats() will create the initialized
# statistics object if it does not exist
# for the team, yet.
hs = table.get(homeTeam,Stats())
gs = table.get(guestTeam,Stats())

hs.games += 1
gs.games += 1

# Now make the comparisons and modify the
hs.win += 1
gs.loss += 1
... etc.
```

**Update:** If you want to use a list then probably the [Bkkknght's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20820313/1346705) is the closest to your initial approach. Searching for the most efficient solution is not the goal here because of the small number of the teams.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've already built my program around storing the objects in a list, thus avoiding the use of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to turn your two loops into a single loop:

```
game_teams = (home_team, away_team)
game_score = score.split("-")

for t in self.teams:
    if t in game_teams:
        if t == home_team:
            scored, allowed = game_score
        else: # t == away_team, so reverse the scores
            allowed, scored = game_score

        # now update t using scored and allowed, rather than the "raw" scores
        t.games += 1

        if scored > allowed:
            t.win += 1
            t.points += 3
        elif scored == allowed:
            t.tie += 1
            t.points += 1
        else:
            t.loss += 1

        # etc
```

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't seem to update my table. It doesn't give me an error or anything. Any ideas what could be wrong? (I've of course adjusted the variablenames and such so it fits my program)

Comment: Hmm I have no idea what could be going wrong. Try putting some diagnostic code in the loop perhaps, e.g. `print(t, game_teams)` just after the `for`? That might help you spot where it's going wrong.

Comment: It seems to update all of the teams stats since "if scored > allowed:" etc are excluded from the "t == home_team". Do you have any ideas how I should place the if's and for's to make it only work for the intended teams?

Comment: @user3142412: Without seeing your code I'm not sure I can help much. Perhaps double check your indentation and `if` conditions?